# Creating Amazon DynamoDB Table Items from a JSON File

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have a json with ~100,000 elements that I would like to insert into a dynamodb table. Since this only needs to be done once, a simple manual process would suffice for me. Unfortunately, on the dynamodb page there is only the possibility to add single elements, as far as I can see. Another possibility would be to iterate through the json with a loop and write each element individually into the database. Since this would require 100,000 writes, I am now looking for an alternative. What is the possibility to solve this problem quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Be aware that you can temporarily increase a DynamoDB table's write capacity for ingestion. Example here in [steps 5-7](https://amazon-dynamodb-labs.com/design-patterns/ex1capacity/step5.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100k writes would probably take a few minutes if writing slowly. You do have the ability to use [DynamoDB Import from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html) feature, however, your data would need to be in DDB-JSON format, meaning you would have to run a process to convert JSON to DDB-JSON. Then you would need to upload the file to S3 before importing.

My suggestion would be to use whatever compute you are familiar with, EC2, Lambda or local machine and just write the items using a loop. You can speed it up using BatchWriteItems where you can write 25 items in a batch.

Or if you use Python, you can use Boto3's [batch_writer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/table/batch_writer.html) where you can pass it all the items in a JSON array and it will do the BatchWriteItems on your behalf, inlcuding handling retries.